# howto autocomplete jquery and codeigniter session

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, session

friends i have several problem to found a good tutorial/howto based on
codeigniter and the jquery function "autocomplete"

in my program i have the session

I post some code

**CONTROLLER :**

```
function __construct()
{       
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();      
}

function check_in_client() {
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $this->load->library('javascript');
    $this->load->view('check_in_cliente');
    if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result= $this->membership_model->check_in_client($_GET['term']);
            if(count($result) > 0) {
                foreach($result as $pr) 
                    $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
```

**MODEL :**

```
function check_in_client($name) {
    $this->db->like('nome',$name, 'both');
    return $this->db->get('clienti')->result();
}
```

**VIEW :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#client_name').autocomplete({
                source: "<?php echo site_url('site/check_in_client/?'); ?>"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" placeholder="nome" />
```

**the result** in the browser is when i put somethingh in the input bar is

**No search results.**

someone help me ?

thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: Have you checked the exact URL that autocomplete is calling to make sure it works? Eg Try `site/check_in_client/?term=some_name` in your browser. Also check your browser's dev tools when the call is being made to make sure it's the correct url. I'm not positive, but I think you may need to remove the '?' at the end of the site_url().

Comment: it doesnt work anywhere

Answer (score 1):

change `$_GET['term']` to `$_REQUEST['term']`

```
function check_in_client() {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->view('check_in_cliente');
        if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {
            $result= $this->membership_model->check_in_client($_REQUEST['term']);
                if(count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach($result as $pr) 
                        $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
                    echo json_encode($arr_result);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps you!

change `$_GET['term']` to `$this->input->get('term', TRUE)`

```
function check_in_client() {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->view('check_in_cliente');
        if(isset($this->input->get('term', TRUE)) {
            $result= $this->membership_model->check_in_client($this->input->get('term', TRUE));
                if(count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach($result as $pr) 
                        $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
                    echo json_encode($arr_result);
                }
            }
```